# What is the range of connectivity for maximal IC-planar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-drawing

A graph is **IC-planar** if it admits a drawing in the plane with
at most one crossing per edge and such that two pairs of crossing edges
share no common end vertex. A graph $G$ is *maximal* in a graph class $G$ if no edge can be added to G without
violating the defining class.

We can appropriately add edges to a triangulated graph so that the final graph becomes a maximal IC-planar graph. Therefore, constructing a 3-connected, 4-connected, and 5-connected maximal IC-planar graph is always achievable.

My question is whether there exist maximal IC-planar graphs with cut vertices, whether there are maximal IC-planar graphs with connectivity 2, and whether there exist 6-connected maximal IC-planar graphs.

Comment: I have solved this question; it will appear in my further paper.